# How do I resolve this error when installing the Forge source?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-forge

I try to install the forge source (build number 953) but when I run install.cmd it shows this error:

```
================ Forge ModLoader Setup Start ===================
MCP Detected already, not downloading
Setting up MCP
Patching commands.py
patching file commands.py
    Commands patch applied successfully
Copying FML conf
Creating Repackaged data
    Creating re-packaged srg
    Creating re-packaged exc
    Creating re-packaged MCP patches
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py", line 76, in <module>
    decompile=options.decompile, gen_conf=False)
  File "install.py", line 17, in fml_main
    disable_assets=disable_assets)
  File "D:\MCP\fml\fml.py", line 1013, in decompile_minecraft
    pre_decompile(mcp_dir, fml_dir, disable_assets=disable_assets)
  File "D:\MCP\fml\fml.py", line 1061, in pre_decompile
    download_minecraft(mcp_dir, fml_dir)
  File "D:\MCP\fml\fml.py", line 1125, in download_minecraft
    failed = download_libraries(mcp_dir, version_json['libraries'], mc_info['natives_dir']) or failed
  File "D:\MCP\fml\fml.py", line 1181, in download_libraries
    headers = get_headers(url)
  File "D:\MCP\fml\fml.py", line 173, in get_headers
    response = urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url))
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 126, in urlopen
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 406, in open
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 519, in http_response
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 444, in error
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 378, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.pyc", line 527, in http_error_default
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Error 403: Forbidden; you're trying to access a site that's been blocked, or has blocked your IP.  Are you at home?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that Mojang changed the download locations for their files, and with the whole Forge team preparing for the 1.7.X version launch, they aren't able or willing to touch the "stable" 1.6.4 one.

The fix involves editing your `fml/fml.py` file (located in the same folder as the `install.cmd` or `install.sh` file you're using to set it up).

In line 1149, change

```
default_url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries'
```

to

```
default_url = 'https://libraries.minecraft.net'
```

In line 1242, change

```
base_url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Resources'
```

to

```
base_url = 'http://resources.download.minecraft.net'
```

Source: http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/topic,14567.0.html

Comment: There seem to be [questions about where the `fml/fml.py` script can be found](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/147501/how-do-i-install-forge-1-6-4). Do you think you could add that information to your answer?

Comment: @IQAndreas: It's like somebody never looked at the contents of the forge folder they just unpacked and plan to use ...

Comment: I can't seem to find fml.py at all in the 1.7.2 forge, installer, universal and source.

Comment: @3ventic: That's because the question and answer is about the 1.6.4 version.

Comment: Weird.  Mine didn't have any of that stuff in the `fml/fml.py` file (and, yes, I'm using 1.6.4!) -- but it looks like the data is there in the `fml/mc_versions.cfg` which appears to be a standard `.ini` type file.

Comment: Hmmm.. still had trouble with it, but found this on the googles: http://terrafirmacraft.com/f/topic/5295-compiling-forge-965/ -- it was immensely helpful. -- looks like I was almost there, I had been putting those values under `[default]` instead of `[1.6.4]`.