# Minecrat forge 1.6.4 not running?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have installed minecraft 1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.953 and when i try to run it gives following error

```
Refreshing local version list...
Launcher 3.0.0 started on windows...
Current time is Dec 17, 2013 2:46:21 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_45'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'
Refreshing remote version list...
No internet connection!
Couldn't download resources
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Resources/
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown    Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.c.a(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Download job 'Resources' skipped as there are no files to download
Job 'Resources' finished successfully
Refresh complete.
Loaded 5 profile(s); selected 'minecraft Forge'
Getting syncinfo for selected version
Queueing library & version downloads
Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (8 threads, 22 files)
Couldn't download    https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/lau nchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Finished downloading     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-  1.0.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403)   but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\co decjorbis-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server  (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading   C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-   platform\2.9.0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.0-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries':   Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading     C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-  2.9.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403)   but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading    C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-  jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to   server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-    io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to   server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-  simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading   C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar for job 'Version & Libraries':     Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons- lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server  (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading  C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo- 2.25_fixed.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with   403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\so undsystem-20120107.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Couldn't download  https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for  job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown  Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4- Forge9.11.1.953\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.953.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect  to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading  C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput- 2.0.5.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403)  but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading  C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\4.1\asm-all- 4.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403)  but have local file, assuming it's good
Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/launchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Finished downloading C:\Users\Akash\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries': Couldn't connect to server (responded with 403) but have local file, assuming it's good
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/launchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/launchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/launchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Gave up trying to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/lzma-0.0.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Couldn't download  https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/lau nchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(Unknown  Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$0(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Gave up trying to download   https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/net/minecraft/launchwrapper/1.8/lau    nchwrapper-1.8.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 2 failure(s)!
```

Comment: You're getting a 403 Forbidden.  Where are you trying to download this from?

Comment: @Frank The 403 is a symptom. When you look a bit higher it says "No internet connection"

Comment: @Arperum Thing is, a web server doesn't return a 403 unless they actually manage to connect to it.  If anything, he should be getting a 404 with no internet connection.

Comment: @Frank good point. I feel stupid now. That errorlog is saying contradictory things in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that Mojang changed the download locations for their files, and with the whole Forge team preparing for the 1.7.X version launch, they aren't able or willing to touch the "stable" 1.6.4 one.

See [Martin Sojka's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/145721/39891) for how to fix this.

Comment: can i downloas the libraries manually

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to. Not sure though. It's way easier to just let forge do it's job and install them for you.

Comment: i have tried hundred of time but it is not downloading it

Comment: Is minecraft blocked by your firewall? Make sure it isn't.

Comment: no it is not, i have also tried switching off the firewall

Comment: have downloaded the file manually can you tell me were to place it

Comment: There are multiple files that are not downloaded see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145696/error-with-installing-the-forge-source) for a solution.