# minecraft cannot download versions and libraries

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

How do I fix [this error](http://pastebin.com/BJCTXuvL) in Minecraft?
I tried changing my Internet settings and Java settings but it did not work.

```
Launcher 1.0.8 (through bootstrap 0) started on windows...
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_45'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
Loaded 1 profile(s); selected 'New Profile'
Trying to log in...
Logged in successfully
Couldn't download resources
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Resources/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionManager.getResourceFiles(VersionManager.java:263)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.VersionManager.downloadResources(VersionManager.java:251)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Download job 'Resources' skipped as there are no files to download
Job 'Resources' finished successfully
Installed PartialVersion{id='1.6.4', updateTime=Thu Sep 19 23:52:37 SGT 2013, releaseTime=Thu Sep 19 23:52:37 SGT 2013, type=RELEASE}
Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (8 threads, 19 files)
Going to play offline as '(Default)'...
Getting syncinfo for selected version
Queueing library & version downloads
Installed PartialVersion{id='1.6.4', updateTime=Thu Sep 19 23:52:37 SGT 2013, releaseTime=Thu Sep 19 23:52:37 SGT 2013, type=RELEASE}
Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (8 threads, 19 files)
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/codecjorbis-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Downloadable.java:85)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:10)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/soundsystem-20120107.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/paulscode/codecwav/20101023/codecwav-20101023.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Couldn't download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/google/guava/guava/14.0/guava-14.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Downloadable.java:85)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:10)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[...similar errors omitted...]

Gave up trying to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.lang.RuntimeException: Server responded with 403
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.Downloadable.download(Downloadable.java:85)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:10)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Gave up trying to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.0/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Gave up trying to download https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/libraries/com/paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 18 failure(s)!
```

Comment: related (not duplicate, same error, but the other one is about installing forge): [How do I resolve this error when installing the Forge source?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145696/how-do-i-resolve-this-error-when-installing-the-forge-source)

Comment: The launcher says you're offline.Did you put your account username and password right?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely your launcher is out of date and is trying to get files from locations they are no longer at or have access to (though 403 error shown in your pastebin pretty much says what you are trying to get at is not accessible).

I would suggest just trying to update your launcher and making sure you are logged into your minecraft account properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, delete your .minecraft folder, download the latest launcher from https://minecraft.net/download. Then try creating a new profile from launcher, leave the settings default.

Answer (score -1):

For first, it's the LWJGL's logo.

Why do you have it?

I think you're using a cracked/unsupported launcher for Minecraft. In November (after the release 1.7.2), Mojang locked his resource servers for official launcher only, so other launchers can't download the Minecraft's resource files (sound, language, and the workbench icon).

If you see this LWJGL icon, it means that your Minecraft resource files are missing. Not the icon is only missing: You don't have any sound, and you can't change language: it stays on English.

How to fix that?

- If you have bought Minecraft, you have to use the official launher from minecraft.net. It will download the resource files.
- If you use a cracked launcher, you have to download resource files manually from a 3rd-party site. Sorry, but I can't help with that, because it's illegal.

Good luck :)

Comment: `Trying to log in...
Logged in successfully` Incorrect. If you theory was right, then this would not have been shown

Comment: Not entirely true - I've actually written [a library for legitimate custom launchers to use](https://github.com/DiamondSwordDev/Perspective) that downloads the assets fine.